# How to fetch txt file from whatsapp fileprovider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-permissions, android-fileprovider

I trying to get whatsapp chat txt file.
As i saw on Android documentation:

```
private void handleSentMultipleAttached(Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<Uri> attachedFilesUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (attachedFilesUris != null) {
        for (Uri uri : attachedFilesUris) {
            File f = new File(uri.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

The uri is:

```
content://com.whatsapp.fileprovider/external/.Shared/WhatsApp%20Chat%20with.txt
```

But i can't use the f file because file is not exist in that path.

I'v already open permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY" />
```

What should i do so i can use the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i can't use the f file because file is not exist in that path.

That is not a filesystem path. That is a `content:` `Uri` from a `ContentProvider`.

> What should i do so i can use the file?

It is not a file, any more than this Web page is a file on the Stack Overflow Web server.

You can use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by that `Uri`. You can get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`, such as an `Activity` or `Service`.

Comment: You can expand your explanation?

Comment: @motis10: Well, there is [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) and [the documentation for `openInputStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) and [some documentation on using a `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#open-client). Otherwise, please feel free to explain what you do not understand.